# How to filter table row based on the date range pick (starting date - end date) in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm setting up a table in reactjs in which i want to filter the table based on the starting date to end date or from-to date picked in the filter options, and want to display all the rows which falls between the dates selected or picked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming you have an array for rows of your table to render them. So, you can logically compare date objects to filter rows, like

```
arrayForRows.filter(row=>row.dateColumn>startDate&&row.dateColumn<endDate)
```